# What is the difference between ViewModelProviders and ViewModelProvider class?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I saw two classes with a similar name, ViewModelProviders, and ViewModelProvider. Can anyone explain what are the difference between these classes? which class actually provide the ViewModel?

Comment: `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated. Use `ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel::class.java)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**ViewModelProviders**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) *(belongs to Maven artifact android.arch.lifecycle:extensions)* is a class from `android.arch.lifecycle` package which contains utilities methods for [ViewModelStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelStore) class & returns you object of `ViewModelProvider` class when you use `of()` method from it.

So, you can think of as wrapper around library class for `ViewModelProvider`.

On the other hand, [**ViewModelProvider**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) *(belongs to Maven artifact android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel)* is class that provides `ViewModels` for a scope. So it's default `ViewModelProvider` for an `Activity` or a `Fragment` can be obtained from `ViewModelProviders` class.

So, yes ! this is the main class that provides core logic for your `ViewModel`, but you'll need to obtain it from `ViewModelProviders` which returns you **this class** to obtain `ViewModel` from.

**Edit:**

After [ViewModel version 2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0):

Class `ViewModelProviders` has been deprecated and we can now use `ViewModelProvider` directly by creating it's new instance for getting `ViewModel`.

Something like this: `ViewModelProvider(this).get(SomeViewModel::class.java)`

Comment: Which api should we use then?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you're using latest alpha dependency of `ViewModel` then this API has changed how we used to get `ViewModel`s from `ViewModelProviders`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede need your help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421965/user-login-is-not-working-using-retrofit-and-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModelProviderS class provides instances of ViewModelProvider class.Your call to ViewModelProviders.of("this") creates and returns a ViewModelProvider associated with the activity.

ViewModelProvider on the other hand provides instances of ViewModel of the Activity. Calling the ViewModelProviders.get(ExampleViewModel::class.java) returns an instance of ExampleViewModel class

These functions usually go together like:

```
ViewModelProviders.of("this").get(ExampleViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

@andritK, it seems `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated now. The docs says we can straight away use **ViewModelProvider** in this case now. then how about changing below codes to the following:
**FROM**

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory, body: T.() -> Unit): T {
    val vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[T::class.java]
    vm.body()
    return vm
}
```

**TO**

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory, body: T.() -> Unit): T {
    val vm = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(T::class.java)
    vm.body()
    return vm
}
```

> Does this work?

Comment: What is the need for `reified`?